# How to boot an os completely written in C++?

Tags: c++, operating-system, boot

I wrote the basis for a simple OS in C++ and have had no luck with researching how to write a simple bootloader for this OS to possibly use with GRUB or something similar to make writing the bootloader a bit easier. Take a look at [it's GitHub repository](https://sykeben.github.io/overos) to see what code I'm trying to boot.

The OS requires some very simple things to run and be fully functional. It needs to be able to use the standard C++ libraries (such as `iostream`, `fstream`, `string.h`, and possibly `iomanip`). It also needs to have any sort filesystem (NTFS, FAT, FAT32, Ext4, etc). And, most importantly, it needs a way to execute other executables (through `system()` or any safer methods).

Currently it can run executables (called "commands") from a hardcoded directory, run an executable before fully loading the kernel (called "kautorun"), and can be compiled and run over top of Win32, and GNU/Linux.

Preferably, I want to be able to make writing the bootloader easy and I'm thinking using GRUB and some special compiler commands would do it. I'm just not sure how to approach this. What can I do to get this working? And, am I approaching this from the wrong angle?

EDIT: To narrow it down a bit, I need a bootloader to run these executables, preserve the C++ libraries I used, and keep the directory structure intact. Hopefully that narrows it down enough and takes this question out of hold for being too broad.

Comment: Standard C++ libraries + filesystem + even just being able to run processes =/= "very simple thing". You should give the osdev wiki a look, because you think you have access to much more things than you really have.

Comment: Did grub progress enough to relive the OS from the need of going from 16 bit real-mode to 32/64 bit protected mode? You need to write that part in assembly

Comment: @MichaelVeksler, actually the GRUB does do it for you, you will only need a few lines of inline-assembly to set up the stack and get the information passed from GRUB.

Comment: @r3musn0x is that true? If it is, how would you implement it, because that sounds awesome!

Comment: That looks like a fun project, Ben. Very ambitious. I think that you are right: focus on GRUB, but also attend to the suggestion of @MichaelVeksler: the x86 16-bit real mode might need some attention from you because of the layered procedure by which x86 boots. It's complicated, and is more than I know. Good luck.

Comment: Someone has voted to close? No, I don't think so. This is an awesome question. If unsure, just follow OP's hyperlink.

Comment: How did [Haiku](https://www.haiku-os.org/) do it?  That's a OS written in C++.

Comment: Thanks @thb for your enthusiam! I really am new to this so all the support your giving is really making me feel welcome in this community.

Comment: @Eljay that's exactly how this started, Haiku puzzles me in how it did it.

Comment: @BenjaminSykes I am glad but, admittedly, am just passing through here. I am a Debian Developer, so Debian rather than Stack Overflow would probably be my community. (This would also explain why I like to the look of your project so.)

Comment: BTW, at the executable level, the source language of the OS is meaningless.  The OS could be written in FORTRAN (as some were).  You could write an OS in an interpreted language as well (as long as the interpreter is part of the OS).

Comment: @r3musn0x : If using C++ there is extra work needed to iterate over the CTORs(global constructors) and some corresponding magic in the linker script.

Comment: On a side note, there is a video series on writing an OS in C++ using GRUB/Mulitboot for a bootloader. It is called WYOOS (Write your own Operating System): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rnA6wpF0o4&list=PLHh55M_Kq4OApWScZyPl5HhgsTJS9MZ6M  .

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'll take a look at the WYOOS series, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write a booting OS takes a lot of work.  I would recommend using something like [IncludeOS](https://www.includeos.org/) which will allow you to write a single "application" which will boot.

Writing a boot loader, you will need to know the hardware you are booting on.  For PC's there are two main ones.

- [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS)
- [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface)

Since your talking about GRUB then most likely talking about a BIOS machine.

A BIOS machine boots into 16bit x86 mode with BIOS services that you can use.  It boots by loading the first sector of the master HD into address "0x0000:0x7C00" and then jumps to it.

This first sector is "normally" a MBR with a partition table. One is marked as the "boot" partition (or you get some sort of "menu" boot).  The MBR code then loads the first sector of the booting partition into address "0x0000:0x7C00" and then jumps to it.

The first sector of a partition is normally called a [BPB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block).

The BPB is normally a mixture of data about the partition type (FAT,NTFS,EXT,etc) and code to start the OS boot.  Since it's only 1 sector that is loaded you are very limited for code space.  So this is written in assembler only, this code uses the BIOS services to find the "real" boot code for the OS within the filesystem and load it into memory and jumps to it.

UEFI is similar to BIOS but provides a complete booting environment where you write a EUFI application and the boot menu configuration runs this application to boot your OS.  This application can be written in C++ and you use the UEFI services (which include a lot more services than BIOS as you get API's for network and graphics for example).  This boot code normally uses the boot configuration to load the initial OS booting code from the partition and jump to it (and also turn off UEFI services as well as they are not normally used from some point onwards).

From this point what the OS booting code does highly depends on the OS that is booting.  They normally:

- Switches to protected mode and sets up a [protection ring environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring)
- Loads "drivers" to handle specific hardware (PC legacy HW and PNP HW)

IncludeOS makes it easier by providing a very simplified versions of the above into a simple library.

Comment: That's actually really cool that something like that exists! I will for sure take a shot at using IncludeOS.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, your code has nothing to do with writing an OS. It's just a console application capable of running a few commands and it's not even close to a shell implementation.

To get a better idea of what it takes to write an OS, I recommend you to read at least a few of the beginner articles at [OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page). You should also take a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/freestanding) to see which C++ standard headers are available in a freestanding environment (that is an environment without OS). You will notice that there are no file system or I/O headers there, and no `system()` function because there is no shell to run it.

Basically, all this means that developing your own OS is to implement all of this functionality on your own: memory management, multi-tasking, I/O, etc... Also you do need a bootloader to boot your OS and you can use GRUB to make thing easier for you, however the bootloader won't provide you with any of those other things (processes, I/O, etc...), the only thing it does is transfer control to your code and after that you're on your own.

Regarding using C++ for OS development, yes, you can write **most of the OS** using C++ but you will still have to at least use inline-assembly for a hardware specific tasks that just can't be expressed using C++, such as: port I/O for communication with hardware, loading special processor registers (control registers, model-specific registers), loading global-descriptor table (which describes memory segments), loading interrupt-descriptor table (which sets handler for hardware-interrupts) and maybe more...

Comment: I don't think so. I for one have never set up process no. 1 and gotten it to run on the bare processor, nor have I ever worked directly from GRUB without a kernel. Maybe you have done, but this is a cool project *even if it never gets as far as switching between tasks.* The OSDev Wiki might be a good resource, though.

Comment: @thb, basically the code that the OP provided is just a beginning of the shell implementation and while shell is an important concept in a Unix-like OS, it is, however, just a user-mode program that relies on already existing OS kernel and just provides it's functionality (creating processes, redirecting I/O, etc...) to the user. BTW it doesn't make sense to use `system()` in a shell implementation because it basically means that it relies on already existing shell.